# How to solve Error ORA-16810: multiple errors or warnings detected for the member?

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, dataguard

Oracle Enterprise Manager 13.5 constantly reports Error ORA-16810: multiple errors or warnings detected for the member.

```
...
Target type=Database Instance 
Target name=xxxx 
Categories=Availability 
Message=The Data Guard status of xxxxxx is Error ORA-16810: multiple errors or warnings detected for the member.
...
Event Type=Metric Alert 
Event name=dataguard:dg_status 
Metric Group=Data Guard Status
Metric=Data Guard Status
Metric value=Error ORA-16810: multiple errors or warnings detected for the member
```

Checking dgmgrl on the target machine, the apply lag seem to be solved already. How to solve this?